# How to write a closed form expression for $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$ in terms of $a_0$ and $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form

I am given this:$$\sum _{i=1}^n a_i = n^2-n,a_0=4$$
How do I write a closed form expression for
$$\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}$$in terms of n?

I know that for $$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}$$ the expression would be $a_i$=n(n-3)-2.

But for $i$=0, I am lost.

Comment: If I get it right, you want to know what is $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$? If this is the case, then isn't it simply $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i=a_0+n^2-n$?

Comment: You've got no arguments in your 2nd and 3rd summations, so you need to edit this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the last bit while typing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what $a_0$ is, you can only say that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i$$

If you know that $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = n^2 - n$$

is true for **every** value of $n$, then you can continue to write $$a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i = a_0 + (n-1)^2 - (n-1)$$

Comment: If $a_0$ = 4, then would it still be the same?

Comment: @christinaqwer Why would it not be?

Comment: In that case, does i=0 or does it equal to 1? Sorry I'm a little bit confused here.

Comment: @christinaqwer $i$ does not equal anything. It's a dummy variable. It dissapears after you do the sum.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck at the part where there's i=0 and i=1.

Comment: @christinaqwer I actually have no idea what you are asking. Your sentences, mathematically, make no sense. As I said, $i$ does not equal either $0$ or $1$. For example, in $$\sum_{i=0}^3 i,$$ $i$ does not equal anything, since the sum is equal to $0+1+2+3$. There is no $i$ in here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is since that I know $$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}$$ the expression would be $a_i$=n(n-3)-2, does this answer also apply to this circumstance?